# How to read a txt and store its data in a list?

Tags: react-graph-vis

```
pathfile = "C:\Users\gk\Documents\toread"


readfile= open(pathfile+'.txt', 'r')
```

I tried just to make a variable the as the `redfile`

```
newList = []
newList = readfile
readfile.close()
```

so then send in a fetch that list for a graph.

But I justs get a None when I generate a graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just Try to use a for loop to save every line of the txt in the new list

```
pathfile = "C:\Users\gk\Documents\toread"


readfile= open(pathfile+'.txt', 'r')


newList = []

for i in readfile:
        newList.append(i)
readfile.close()
```